# How does Ruby 1.9 handle character cases in source code?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

In Ruby 1.8 and earlier,

```
Foo
```

is a constant (a Class, a Module, or another constant).  Whereas

```
foo
```

is a variable.  The key difference is as follows:

```
module Foo
  bar = 7
  BAZ = 8
end

Foo::BAZ
# => 8

Foo::bar
# NoMethodError: undefined method 'bar' for Foo:Module
```

That's all well and good, but Ruby 1.9 [allows UTF-8 source code](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/04/fun-with-ruby-1.html).  So is `℃` "uppercase" or "lowecase" as far as this is concerned?  What about `⊂` (strict subset) or `Ɖfoo`?

Is there a general rule?

*Later:*

Ruby-core is already considering some of the mathematical operators.  For example

```
module Kernel
  def √(num)
    ...
  end
  def ∑(*args)
    ...
  end
end
```

would allow

```
x = √2
y = ∑(1, 45, ...)
```

I would love to see

```
my_proc = λ { |...| ... }

x ∈ my_enumerable  # same as my_enumerable.include?(x)

my_infinite_range = (1..∞)

return 'foo' if x ≠ y

2.21 ≈ 2.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get IRB to accept UTF-8 characters, so I used a test script (`/tmp/utf_test.rb`).

"λ" works fine as a variable name:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
λ = 'foo'
puts λ

# from the command line:
> ruby -KU /tmp/utf_test.rb
foo
```

"λ" also works fine as a method name:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
Kernel.class_eval do
  alias_method :λ, :lambda
end

(λ { puts 'hi' }).call

# from the command line:
> ruby -KU /tmp/utf_test.rb:
hi
```

It doesn't work as a constant, though:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
Object.const_set :λ, 'bar'

# from the command line:
> ruby -KU /tmp/utf_test.rb:
utf_test.rb:2:in `const_set': wrong constant name λ (NameError)
```

Nor does the capitalized version:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
Object.const_set :Λ, 'bar'

# from the command line:
> ruby -KU /tmp/utf_test.rb:
utf_test.rb:2:in `const_set': wrong constant name Λ (NameError)
```

My suspicion is that constant names must start with a capital ASCII letter (must match `/^[A-Z]/`).

Answer (score 3):

OK, my joking answer didn't go down so well.

[This mailing list question, with answer from Matz](http://www.nabble.com/String-upcase-downcase-with-UTF-8-strings-in-Ruby-1.9-td18372062.html) indicates that Ruby 1.9's built in `String#upcase` and `String#downcase` methods will only handle ASCII characters.

Without testing it myself, I would see this as strong evidence that all non-ascii characters in source code will likely be considered lowercase.

Can someone download and compile the latest 1.9 and see?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what ruby would do if you used extended UTF8 characters as identifiers in your source code, but I know what I would do, which would be to slap you upside the back of the head and tell you DON'T DO THAT

Answer (score 1):

> I would love to see

```
my_proc = λ { |...| ... }

x ∈ my_enumerable  # same as my_enumerable.include?(x)

my_infinite_range = (1..∞)

return 'foo' if x ≠ y

2.21 ≈ 2.2
```

I would love to see someone trying to type that program on an English keyboard :P

Comment: Your apprehension is definitely warranted, but I'd gladly build Textmate macros to turn memberof + tab into ∈. The typing isn't any shorter than include?, but I think the code says what I mean more clearly.  I'm sure it's a taste issue; I just really liked my discrete math classes in college.

Answer (score 1):

In **Ruby 1.9.2-p0 (YARV)** the result is the same as in the original post (i.e., Foo::bar #=> # NoMethodError: undefined method 'bar' for Foo:Module). Also, letters with accent are unfortunately not considered as being upper nor lower and related methods produce no result.

Examples:

```
"á".upcase
=> "á"
"á" == "Á".downcase
=> false
```