# Method name format

Tags: ruby, methods

What strings can be a method name for Ruby? I particularly want to know in what way a non word character can be part of a method name. Please give an exhaustive set of rules/lists.

**Edit**
Phrogz' answers to the question that Josh Lee links has a link to the following page, but that is from several years ago, and is outdated. For example, `Proc#()` is missing. Does anyone know of an updated one?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378670/what-is-a-ruby-regex-to-match-a-function-name

Comment: @Josh Lee I looked at one of the answers there, but it seems outdated.

Answer (score 3):

According to pickaxe (*Programming Ruby*, The Pragmatic Programmers):

> Local variables, method parameters, and method names should all
>   start with a lowercase letter or an underscore... Following this initial character, a name can be any combination of letters, digits, and underscores (with the proviso that the character following an @ sign may not be a digit)... Method names may end with the characters ?, !, and =.

Comment: `Array#[]` does not fit into this description. Nor does `Proc#()`.

Comment: Valid point, well made. I did think as I quoted that I was maybe missing something.

Comment: Although I note that, while `def []` is fine, the parser has distinct difficulty with `def ()`

Comment: `foo.(bar)` is syntax sugar for `foo.call(bar)`

Answer (score 3):

Any sequence of Unicode characters is a valid method name. For example:

```
class Test
  define_method :'    ???    _    µµµµ . . . ' do puts 'Hello' end
end

Test.instance_methods
# => [:'    ???    _    µµµµ . . . ']

Test.new.send :'    ???    _    µµµµ . . . '
# Hello
```

Comment: I didn't know it what that flexible. This is a very informative answer. But I have a further question. Not all of them seem to be callable without using `send`. Which of them are callable without using `send`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASCII, UTF-8 and Unicode characters as the names of methods. I imagine that whitespace (`\s`) characters wouldn't work simply because the parser would complain. Just set up the magic line so Ruby knows what to expect.

http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/10/fun_with_unicode_1.html and http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Unicode_variable_names#Ruby and http://www.sw.it.aoyama.ac.jp/2009/pub/IUC33-ruby1.9/. Phrogz has a nice regex in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379197/128421 which covers the ASCII characters.

Also, here on Stack Overflow, this has been discussed nicely in "[How does Ruby 1.9 handle character cases in source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764/how-does-ruby-1-9-handle-character-cases-in-source-code)". Because of the age of that question I'm not marking this as a duplicate, but it does deserve to be referenced.

The question that should be asked though, is, should non-ASCII characters be used in method names? Yes, they're cute, and they might be symbolic, but they can be a pain to type, especially for those who don't have the ability to type in the characters for one reason or another. Creating a method name or constant containing π or λ might be hard to type if they're in a gem.

Also note that `$KCODE`, mentioned on several of the linked paged, is now deprecated in Ruby 1.9.1+ so you'll need to use magic lines.

Comment: I am not interested in using non-ASCII characters here.

Comment: After reading Jörg W Mittag's answer, I understand what you meant.